# Vue.js BootstrapVue : Veevalidate does not show the validation error mesage for phone number input

Tags: validation, vue.js, vue-component, bootstrap-vue, vee-validate

In my Laravel+Vue.js SPA ( Single Page Application) I am using the phone number input validation package from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-phone-number-input), BootstrapVue from [here](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/)  and Veevalidate from [here](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/forms.html#validate-before-submit) .

I think I need to show only the code inside my component file. The `vue-phone-number-input` component shows blue border and HTML5 error message tooltip (?) upon invalid data  but **no error message appears in red as it happens with `name` field**.  My code follows in `EditProfile.vue`:

```
<ValidationObserver ref="form" v-slot="{ passes }">

        <div id="registration_form">

            <b-form @submit.prevent="passes(onSubmit)" @reset="resetForm">

                <ValidationProvider vid="name" rules="required|min:2" name="name" v-slot="{ valid, errors }">
                    <b-form-group
                            label="User Name:"
                            label-for="exampleInput1"

                    >
                        <b-form-input
                                type="text"
                                v-model="name"
                                :state="errors[0] ? false : (valid ? true : null)"
                                placeholder="Enter your name"
                        ></b-form-input>

                        <b-form-invalid-feedback id="inputLiveFeedback">{{ errors[0] }}</b-form-invalid-feedback>

                    </b-form-group>

                </ValidationProvider>


                <ValidationProvider vid="mobile" rules="required" name="mobile" v-slot="{ valid, errors }">
                <b-form-group
                        label="Mobile:"
                        label-for="exampleInput1"

                >

                    <vue-phone-number-input

                            v-model="mobile"
                            default-country-code="BD"
                            required
                            disable-leading-trailing-space
                            :state="errors[0] ? false : (valid ? true : null)"
                            @update="updatePhoneNumber"
                            placeholder="Enter Mobile Number"
                    />

                   <b-form-invalid-feedback id="inputLiveFeedback">{{ errors[0] }}</b-form-invalid-feedback>

                </b-form-group>
            </ValidationProvider>



                <b-button type="submit" variant="primary">Submit</b-button>
                <b-button type="reset" variant="danger">Reset</b-button>

            </b-form>

        </div><!-- end of id registration_form-->
    </ValidationObserver>
```

JS part inside `EditProfile.vue` is:

```
import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker';
import { ValidationObserver, ValidationProvider } from "vee-validate";

export default {
    name: "EditProfile",
    components: {
        ValidationObserver,
        ValidationProvider,
        Datepicker
            },
    data: () => ({
        name: "",
        mobile:""
    }),
    methods: {

       onSubmit() {
            console.log("Form submitted yay!");
                  },

        resetForm() {
            this.name = "";
            this.mobile = "";
            requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                this.$refs.form.reset();
            });
        }

}
};
```

When the submit button is pressed then validation works for `name` field nad for `vue-phone-number-input` it also happens  but no error message shows up in red color.

My Vue.js version is 2.6.10 and I used the latest versions of BootstrapVue and Veevalidate (3) as well.

How can I make the error message appear in red color for `vue-phone-number-input` element ?

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap, invalid-feedback is only shown when it has a sibling input (or select etc) that is set to the state `is-invalid`.  Chances are that vue-phone-number-input does not meet that criteria.  So, instead you should make your error message like this:

```
<span class="text-danger" v-show="errors[0]">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
```